How do I get the used service account ID in JavaScript Firebase Cloud Function?
How can I programmatically get the used service account ID which is used by the running JavaScript cloud function?
In other words, how to implement this function:
function getServiceAccountIdUsedByFirebase() {
   /// ???
}

The function is meant to be called after initialization, not before.

This question is similar to: How to get the currently used service account ID?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The other question was misleading, changed subject midflight, had no answers and is now deleted. His question here now is clear and hopes for an answear.
